# Delete install target in CMake

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options

I have a CMake-managed project where is is *never* sensible to execute `make install` after generation of the Makefile. Moreover, if a user types `make install` and puts headers in the default `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` of `/usr/local/include`, then future builds can be contaminated.

I would like to instruct `cmake` to *not* generate an `install` target in the generated Makefile. Is this possible?

Note: A solution getting close to [this](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-June/050761.html) is to `mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX)`, but this only *hides* the option from `ccmake`. Maybe `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /dont/do/this)`?

Comment: `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` are not at all the same thing. I'm not sure what hiding the former accomplishes

Comment: @AlexReinking: I made a typo there. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES.html) to `ON` at the start of your top-level CMakeLists.txt (with a comment explaining why). As it says in the docs:

> If `TRUE`, CMake will neither generate installation rules nor will it generate `cmake_install.cmake` files. This variable is `FALSE` by default.

A quick interaction to prove this works:

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES YES)

add_executable(app main.cpp)

$ cmake -S . -B build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/build
$ cmake --build build/ --target install
ninja: error: unknown target 'install'
```

Attempting to call `install()` will issue the following warning:

```
CMake Warning in CMakeLists.txt:
  CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES was enabled even though installation rules have
  been specified
```

Comment: Actually it warns unconditionally; I used `set(CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES YES QUIET)`

Comment: @user14717 - I don't know what you expect `QUIET` to do there? That command sets the value of `CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES` to `YES;QUIET`, which is truthy.

Comment: @user14717 - I just tested it on CMake 3.23 and using `YES;QUIET` actually breaks the feature: the `install` target is still present and the `install()` commands still run.

Comment: You are correct; my bad.